# Make Argument Lazy without Changing Function Signature?

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

Given:

```
scala> def f(x: Int, y: Int): Int = 
     |   if(x == 55) x else y
f: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

scala> def yFn: Int = {println("y"); 42}
yFn: Int
```

Calling `f(55, yFn)` results in `f`'s evaluation, shown by the `y` print output.

```
scala> f(55, yFn)
y
res0: Int = 55
```

How can `f`'s signature remain the same:

`(Int, Int) => Int`

but have `y` be lazily evaluated **without** making `y` a `by-name` parameter?

Comment: you can't, unless there's some macro magic that allows it. Even if there was a way I would strongly suggest against doing it because that would mean *explicitly violating*  the signature contract and the language specification.

Comment: Even if not recommended, I'd be interested to see such a macro implementation - for my own learning.

Comment: I can't even conceive of a way to do it with a macro.

Comment: @m-z you can if x is known at compile time like in his example, look at my answer. I'm not sure if more can be done

Comment: Do I misunderstand something? It seems doing it with a macro is completely trivial. Just `q"if ($x == 55) $x else $y"`, and it won't evaluate `yFn` if not necessary (of course, it makes `x` "by-name" as well). What won't work is if you want to get a function _object_ out of `f`, e.g. pass it to a method. But any macro which doesn't look at the structure of its arguments effectively takes them by name.

Comment: @AlexyRomanov umh, you're right. I thought you needed a literal constant to do that kind of check. I deleted my previous answer. I'll have to study macros sooner or later :\

Comment: @GiovanniCaporaletti I've turned my comment into an answer to expand on it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Turning `f` into a macro will effectively do what you want:

```
import language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context

object Macros {
  def f(x: Int, y: Int): Int = macro fImpl

  def fImpl(c: Context)(x: c.Expr[Int], y: c.Expr[Int]): c.Expr[Int] = {
    import c.universe._
    c.Expr(q"if ($x == 55) $x else $y")
  }
}
```

`f`'s signature has `Int`, not `=> Int`, but the call `f(55, yFn)` will simply be replaced by `if (55 == 55) 55 else yFn`, which will not evaluate `yFn`.

From this you can see that *any* macro which doesn't look at its arguments' structure effectively takes them by-name; if you want to ensure an argument is evaluated exactly once, you need to assign it to a local variable: `q"{ val x = $x; if (x == 55) x else $y }"`.

However, if you want to convert `f` into an *object* as opposed to a method, this will be lost, because the `apply` method of the generated class won't be a macro (and it can't be; a macro can't implement abstract methods (or override concrete ones, of course)).

Comment: Hi Alexey - thanks for the answer. Could you please include the necessary imports to use this code?